# GET + PUT - Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] error

Tags: javascript, routes, server, syntax

I've tried implementing the same 'function (req, res)' to the last router.route('/profile') but it is not working and I keep getting this error. Any help as to what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
  authUser,
  registerUser,
  logoutUser,
  getUserProfile,
  updateUserProfile,
} = require("../controllers/userController");
const { protect } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");

router.post("/", function (req, res) {
  registerUser;
});
router.post("/auth", function (req, res) {
  authUser;
});
router.post("/logout", function (req, res) {
  logoutUser;
});
router
  .route("/profile")
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);

module.export = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the callback function to the registerUser, authUser, and logoutUser functions. The correct way to call these functions is to pass the req and res parameters as arguments.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
  authUser,
  registerUser,
  logoutUser,
  getUserProfile,
  updateUserProfile,
} = require("../controllers/userController");
const { protect } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");

router.post("/", function (req, res) {
  registerUser(req, res);
});
router.post("/auth", function (req, res) {
  authUser(req, res);
});
router.post("/logout", function (req, res) {
  logoutUser(req, res);
});
router
  .route("/profile")
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);

module.export = router;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if there is a way I can do this with the last one?

```
router
  .route("/profile")
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);
```